# VS2012 - How to GET all files on an existing site?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, web-deployment, azure-web-app-service

Alright, I am obviously missing something here.  I have moved several websites over to Azure to take advantage of all that it has to offer.  Traditionally our team has always used DreamWeaver to ftp up/down and such.  What I don't understand is how I go about getting hooked up to an EXISTING site on Azure.  I can easily setup and web deploy to a NEW site, but I am trying to give the rest of the team access to the sites I have setup and I am lost as to how to approach this.

I have tried the File > Open Web Site route, and the issue with that is it never then saves the project/info anywhere in VS, and we are required to hook back up to it each time.

All of our local sites are on a shared network drive, so we all access the same local resources.  I thought I could simply pass them all the publish profiles and they could then import, get, and then edit and publish files... but it never gives the option to "get all files" from the server.

Hope this makes sense?!  Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: I think using Team Foundation Server makes things like this much more easier.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple developer scenarios, it would be in your best interest to use a source control system such as Git or TFS. This will allow you not only to share the source across team members, but also give you the benefit of tracking changes and merging files that are modified across team members.

If you aren't comfortable with source control, you do still have [access to the files via FTP](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/php/tutorials/website-w-mysql-and-ftp/) or Secure FTP.

You could also use [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) which has the concept of download from server built directly into the tooling.